# Counting nucleotides in DNA sequence string

Tags: python

I have written this function which does not function as I would like it. Any ideas please?
I understand the problem is somehow on the char definition...

```
def count_nucleotides(dna, nucleotide):
    ''' (str, str) -> int

    Return the number of occurrences of nucleotide in the DNA sequence dna.

    >>> count_nucleotides('ATCGGC', 'G')
    2
    >>> count_nucleotides('ATCTA', 'G')
    0
    '''

    num_nucleodites=0

    for char in dna:
        if char is ('A'or'T'or'C'or'G'):
            num_nucleodites=num_nucleodites + 1      
    return num_nucleodites
```

Comment: I see a lot of DNA-related statistics showing up here. Is this a fairly common homework problem?

Comment: Are you counting *all* nucleotides, or just the one that's passed in?

Comment: Your `if char is ('A'or'T'or'C'or'G')` is in fact the same as `if char is 'G'` (due to how `or` operator works).

Answer (score 3):

What about just

```
def count_nucleotides(dna, nucleotide):
    return dna.count(nucleotide)
```

(Mind you, that's probably not going to fly as far as homework is concerned...)

Comment: I thought of it, but then it does not count overlaps

Comment: It looks like you're only looking for a single nucleotide. If you're looking for overlapping sequences, you'll need something a fair bit more sophisticated.

Comment: @user1719345 This function matches the examples in your doc-string. If it's not right, can you give further examples?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're looking for overlapping sequences of more than one nucleotide, according to one of your comments. This can be done with a regular expression:

```
import re
def find_overlapping(needle, haystack):
    return len(re.findall("(?=" + needle + ")", haystack))
```

You can then use it like this:

```
>>> find_overlapping("AGA", "AGAGAGAAGAGAG")
5
```

Comment: +1, the `(?=X)` to force finding overlapping matches is a neat trick.

Answer (score 0):

The `or` condition that you have written does not work the way you think.. It should check `char` with each of them, and then use `or` to separate them, something like this: -

```
if char is 'A' or char is 'T' ... so on:
```

But, you can use a better way using `in` operator.

Try this: -

```
for char in dna:
        if char in 'ATCG':
            num_nucleodites=num_nucleodites + 1
```

---

But since you said in your `question` that you want count of a specific element only, you don't need to check each char with all 4 of them.. Here's how your code should look like using basic for-loop: -

```
def count_nucleotides(dna, nucleotide):
    num_nucleotide = 0
    for char in dna:
        if char == nucleotide:
            num_nucleotide = num_nucletode + 1
    return num_nucleotide
```

Or just: -

```
def count_nucleotides(dna, nucleotide):
    return dna.count(nucleotide)
```

Comment: I would like the function to count only nucleodites that passed

Comment: You should generally not be using  `is` for equality comparison.

Comment: @user1719345.. Yeah that is what my 2nd and 3rd code does. The first one is the just a way to do what you were doing in your code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if char is ('A'or'T'or'C'or'G'):
```

That is evaluating `'A' or 'T'` which returns 'A', then checking if `char` is equal to it - try it in the Python REPL:

```
>>> ('A'or'T'or'C'or'G')
'A'
```

I think what you meant to do was:

```
if char in ('A', 'T', 'C', 'G'):
```

Comment: OK but I would like to count only nucleodites that passed

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "ATAGTTCATGTACCGTTGCAGGGGG"
print [(i,string.count(i)) for i in list("ACTG")]
```